# Finding similiar/equal words in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm workin on a food software like Myfitness Pal and I need to find the very similar/duplicate words (i can't use LIKE operator and write each time a different word I have 7000 records);
for example : "brown sugar" and "brown sugar from Jamaica" are the same thing and I need to find it.

```
SELECT 
group_concat(it.id_ingredient) 'id duplicati ' -- list of the id of the similar words
, group_concat(CASE 
WHEN i.hide_search = 0 THEN it.id_ingredient
ELSE NULL
END  ) 'Id sostitutivo'
, group_concat(it.name) 'Ingrediente' -- list of the similar words 
, IFNULL( it.alias, '-') 'Alias'
, COUNT(it.name)  as CNT -- count of similar words 
FROM ingredients i 
LEFT JOIN ingredients_translation it ON i.id = it.id_ingredient AND it.language_code = 'IT'
WHERE i.id_customer = 1
AND i.isComplex = 0
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(SOUNDEX(it.name), 1,6);
```

thats works well but it can work better  because ["Acqua","Acacia","Acciughe" ] are grouped like similar/same words but they aren't.

Comment: This is not really feasible in SQL, it doesn't have any function to measure similarity of phrases like that.

Comment: You can try full text search instead, but please understand that it's not going to be Google no matter what you try! Better do this with tolls that were designed for text analytics, like elastic search, python or R.